# Checking for null in date field in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET application that crashes when a null date value is returned.

The code line is:

```
excelWorksheet.Cells("A" & xlRowCounter).Value = IIf(IsDBNull(dRow("sysdate")), "", Format(dRow("sysdate"), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Error message:

> ERROR: System.ArgumentException: Argument 'Expression' is not a valid value.

How would I check for a null date, and replace it with "" in my app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `If([condition], [true-part], [false-part])` instead:

```
If(IsDBNull(dRow("sysdate")), "", Format(dRow("sysdate"), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

If you need an extra check to test for nothing, you can do this:

```
If(dRow("sysdate") Is Nothing Or IsDBNull(dRow("sysdate")), "", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dRow("sysdate")))
```

Comment: Glad to be the one to put you over 10k... congrats JJ !!

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper If statement or the new if operator.  The if operator has exactly the same syntax as te old IIF function but only evaluates the arguments it needs to.  The IIF function always evaluates ALL of its arguments.  So even if dRow("sysdate") is null, the last argument to the IIF function is evalulated and causes the error.

Comment: I would... but I LOVE one line if statements |8-)

Comment: @DotNetCookie: You can have your one line if statement, and have it work, just delete delete one of the I's...IIF is a flawed method from 1.1, VB now has a real ternary operator.

Comment: @jmoreno - forgot about the if operator.  I've updated my answer.  I've been stuck in .NET 2 for TOO long! :)

Answer (score 0):

the String class has a IsNullOrEmpty Method.
You can just check the cell with it first, if its true fill it with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Nullable DateTime:

```
Dim sysdate As DateTime? = dRow.Field(Of DateTime?)("sysdate")
Dim result As String = If(sysdate.HasValue, sysdate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "")
```

I presume that dRow is a DataRow from a DataTable

Answer (score 0):

i'm have same problem but i'm using vb.net. 
If Get value from excel worksheet with oledb, check first the cell format to take its value. In this case format is date in excel worksheet, and the way provided by Chris Dunway work done, thx dude.